# Convert a Datatime into a dd-mm-yyyy String in Python - ParseDateTime

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, datetime, time

Hello i'm using the ParseDateTime lib in order to convert from natural text like "3 day ago" into a simple data string.

I use this code:

```
 import parsedatetime as pdt # $ pip install parsedatetime
 import datetime
 c = pdt.Constants()
 p = pdt.Calendar(c)
 output=p.parse(input_data)
```

my output is:

```
(time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=17, tm_hour=1, tm_min=42, tm_sec=15, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=290, tm_isdst=-1),
           1)
```

There is a way to  have DD/MM/YYYY easy string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 1.5 of `parsedatetime` method `Calendar.parse()` returns a tuple. More precisely, a tuple with an inner tuple which is actually the parsed datetime. To get an ordinary `datetime` object you should use `parseDT()` method of the same class:

```
d = p.parseDT("2015/10/11 12:24")
d[0].strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: Works very good! Thanks man